# Проверка деления на 0

Tags: c++

Здесь происходит сложение, вычитание, деление, умножение и сокращение простых дробей. Необходимо сделать проверку, чтобы в знаменателе нельзя было ввести ноль... Пробовала реализовать, но не получилось ( `if (this->b==0)       {cout<<"znam=0";}   else{/*something*/}`)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <locale>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Rational
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    Rational(){ a = 0; b = 0; } // Конструктор по умолчанию
    Rational(const int& _a, const int& _b) // Конструктор с данными
    {
        if (_b < 0)
            exit(1);
        a = _a;
        if (_b)
            b = _b;
        else
            exit(1);
        reduce();//сокращение
    }
    Rational operator+(Rational T)
    {
        Rational Temp;

        if (this->b == T.b){
            Temp.a = this->a + T.a;
            Temp.b = this->b;
        }
        else{
            Temp.b = this->b * T.b;
            Temp.a = (Temp.b / this->b * this->a) + (Temp.b / T.b * T.a);
        }
        Temp.reduce();
        return Temp;
    }
    Rational operator-(Rational T)
    {
        Rational Temp;

        if (this->b == T.b){
            Temp.a = this->a - T.a;
            Temp.b = this->b;
        }
        else{
            Temp.b = this->b * T.b;
            Temp.a = (Temp.b / this->b * this->a) - (Temp.b / T.b * T.a);
        }
        Temp.reduce();
        return Temp;
    }
    Rational operator*(Rational T)
    {
        Rational Temp;
        Temp.a = this->a * T.a;
        Temp.b = this->b * T.b;
        Temp.reduce();
        return Temp;
    }
    Rational operator/(Rational T)
    {
        if (this->b == 0){
            cout << "znam=0";
        }
        else{
            Rational Temp;
            Temp.a = this->a * T.b;
            Temp.b = this->b * T.a;
            Temp.reduce();
            return Temp;
        }
    }
    int NOD(const int& a1, const int& b1)
    {
        int a = abs(a1), b = abs(b1);
        while (a != 0 && b != 0){
            if (a >= b)
                a = a%b;
            else
                b = b%a;
        }
        return a + b;
    }
    void Rational::reduce()
    {
        int nod = NOD(a, b);
        a = a / nod;
        b = b / nod;
    }


    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Rational& drob)
    {
        if (drob.b == 1 || drob.a == 0)
            out << drob.a;
        else
            out << drob.a << '/' << drob.b;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, Rational& b)
    {
        char* str = new char[1024];
        cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
        int i = 0;
        unsigned int bt = 0;
        bool flag = false;
    l1:
        int len = strlen(str) - 1;
        while (str[len] == ' '){
            str[len] = ' ';//NULL;
            goto l1;
        }
        if (strlen(str) == 0) exit(1);

        while (str[i] == ' ') ++i;

        if (str[i] == '-'){
            flag = true;
            ++i;
        }
        while (str[i] != '.' && str[i] != '/' && i < (int)strlen(str)){
            bt = (str[i] - '0') + bt * 10;
            ++i;
        }
        ++i;
        switch (str[i - 1]){
        case '.': {
                      int j = 0;
                      while (i < (int)strlen(str)){
                          bt = (str[i] - '0') + bt * 10;
                          ++i, ++j;
                      }
                      break;
        }
        case '/': {
                      b.b = 0;
                      while (i < (int)strlen(str)){
                          b.b = (str[i] - '0') + b.b * 10;
                          ++i;
                      }
                      break;
        }
        }
        b.a = flag ? -int(bt) : bt;
        b.reduce();
        return istr;
    }
};



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Rational C, D;
    Rational Result;


    cout << "Введите дробь 1 : "; cin >> C; cout << endl;
    cout << "Введите дробь 2 : "; cin >> D; cout << endl;

    cout << C << " - " << D << " = " << C - D << endl;

    cout << C << " + " << D << " = " << C + D << endl;

    cout << C << " * " << D << " = " << C*D << endl;

    cout << C << " / " << D << " = " << C / D << endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему в операторе `/` проверяете только `this->b`, но не проверяете `T.b`?

Да и в конструкторе по умолчанию лучше устанавливать `b=1;`

Comment: @alexlz, сделала вот так   
    if (this->b==0 and T.b==0) 
        {cout<<"znam=0";}
       else
Но все равно не проверяет.
По умолчанию у b установила значение =1

Comment: Во-первых, у Вас проверка на одновременное равенство нулю обоих знаменателей. Лучше, вероятно, `this->b==0 || T.b==0` . И ещё, сообщение лучше выдавать `cout<<"znam=0" << endl;` (см. кэширование)

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо, но все равно не пашет)
Мб вот проверку впихнуть перед этой строкой?
 cout << C <<" / "<< D <<" = " << C/D << endl;
Только я что-то не понимаю как

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрались!

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова это есть хорошо